# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 but boot fails after hard reset

Tags: dual-boot, thinkpad

I installed Windows 7 first then partitioned 30gb in ext4 and installed Ubuntu 64bit and it asked for reboot. I unplugged USB stick installer and hold on a while. It didn't reboot so I power off and booted. It defaultly went to Ubuntu login screen and did not show dual boot option. Any suggestion would be great.. Is that I need to reformat my is of Linux or any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Hold Shift during boot: you will see boot menu. If no Windows entry appears in it, you should boot into Ubuntu and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should find all OSes if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can u see the  windows disk mounted in your ubuntu ?
if you can see windows disk go to terminal and type : `sudo update-grub`